# Add event to calendar

Tags: calendar, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to add an event (with the users permission) to Wp7's calendar from an app? (on Mango)

Comment: He said with the users permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no method to add an event to a calendar.

Comment: I'm sad :( Will there ever be or is this a "security constraint"?

Comment: No idea, I would guess it would be an in API when win 8 hits, but just a guess.